# HTML5 audio и поток воспроизвдения

Tags: аудио, html, html5

Есть поток воспроизведения.

```
 <audio id="player">
         <source src="http://radio.sampo.ru/record.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>

    </div>
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Воспроизведение</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Пауза</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Громкость +</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">Громкость -</button>
```

в концоле пишет, что

> [21:44:23.581] Атрибут "type"
> указанный для "audio/mpeg" не
> поддерживается. Не удалось загрузить
> медиаресурс
> http://radio.sampo.ru/record.mp3. @

Как быть и что делать?

Answer (score 2):

> Не удалось загрузить медиаресурс...

Отдает 404.

Comment: http://radio.sampo.ru ну на самом сайте, же как-то проигрывается? 
GET http://radio.sampo.ru/record.mp3?type=.flv HTTP/1.1